# cannot convert arg from char to const char in c

Tags: c, pointers

```
void squeeze(char str[], char c)
{
    char newstr[150];
    int len = strlen(str);
    char *new_ptr;

    new_ptr = newstr;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i]!=c)
           *new_ptr=str[i];
        new_ptr++;
    }
    printf("The string without the character %c is: %s", c, newstr);
}
```

I tried to run this code, but its showing an error

```
int strcmp(const char*,const char*); cannot convert arg from char to const char
```

I know that the in the `strcmp` prototype, both the args passed should be of `const char`, but i dont know how `str[i]` can be changed to a constant, to modify this code accordingly.
I tried to create a char variable `temp` to hold the `str[i]`, but it isn't working either.

Im also new to pointers, so im not sure if what im doing is correct. Can anyone pls help?

Comment: There is no `strcmp` call in your code

Comment: And (after adding the necessary `#includes`), I do not get any warnings with `gcc -std=c99 -c -Wall -pedantic`

Comment: `but i dont know how str[i] can be changed to a constant` why? Also looks this not function you targeting,you just pass `str` to `strcmp`.Also post more code.

Comment: Yes,I tried using strcmp, but it didn't work. I guess that was because strcmp compares two constant strings, but here the 2nd arg that is passed is a character c and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
void squeeze(char str[], char c)
{
    char newstr[150];
    int len = strlen(str);
    char *new_ptr;

    new_ptr = newstr;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i]!=c)
           *new_ptr++ = str[i];
    }
    *new_ptr = '\0';
    printf("The string without the character %c is: %s", c, newstr);
}
```

Comment: I tried using this code.No errors are being shown but the same string is being shown, the character hasn't been removed from the string.If my input is "deep down in water" and the character is 'e', the expected output is "dp down in watr", but im getting the output as "deep down in water" again.

Comment: /* code in main() */                                    
 printf("Enter a string value: \n");
 gets_s(str,sizeof(str));
 printf("Enter the character to be removed: \n");
 scanf_s("%c",&ch);
 
 squeeze(str,ch);

Comment: @user3387677 `scanf_s` needs size. e.g `scanf_s("%c", &ch, 1);`.

Comment: wow! working! thanks a lot...so is it that scanf and gets_s take in the variables and their size as parameters?